# string to int array conversion c#

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I have a string whose value is '12345678'. I want to assign this value to integer array like the first index of the array contains 1, the second index of array contains 2 so on. So when I write below code and execute then i received value 48 for 0 index and  value 49 for second index, ascii value of my number. 
Declaration

```
int[] ArryDIReadValue = new int[DI_COUNT_CHANNEL];
string binary = Convert.ToString(portData, 2);

ArryDIReadValue = binary.Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
```

Could someone please help to overcome this problem.

Comment: What about `binary.ToCharArray();` ? Afterwards you can parse each char to an int and paste them into your `ArryDIReadValue` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArryDIReadValue = binary.Select(n => (n - '0')).ToArray();
```

Simple and fast.

`n` - is `char`. So, `chars` `0`, `1`, ... `9` has codes 30, 31, ... 39. So, to get int value, we need to substract from every code 30. And we know, 30 is code of char `0`.

Comment: I wondered how it works. can you please explain how it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ToString() such as;

```
ArryDIReadValue = binary.Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks..now it is working...

Answer (score 1):

Use `char.GetNumericValue`:

```
ArryDIReadValue = binary.Select(n => (int)char.GetNumericValue(n)).ToArray();
```

Comment: This will works only when i declare double array like                        
   double [] ArryDIReadValue = binary.Select(n => char.GetNumericValue(n)).ToArray(); otherwise it gives error.

Comment: @PriyankaMehta I edited the answer. It just works as you want.

Comment: Thanks.... Its working now